# Proving $\mathbb{N}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

In $\mathbb{N}$, we define the topology defined by $$T=\emptyset \cup\{\{0,1,2...,n\} :\space n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \mathbb{N}$$

Now I want to prove that $(\mathbb{N},T)$ is not compact.

Suppose $(\mathbb{N},T)$ is compact, then there exists a collecion of open sets $U_i$ so that $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}$. $U_i$ are of the form $\{0,1,2,3,...,i\}$ then there exists $U_j>U_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$ $i\neq j$. Now take $M\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $M>x$ for all $x\in U_j$ . This $M$ exists because $U_j$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and therefore is bounded. Then $M\in \mathbb{N}$ however $M\not\in\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} U_{i}$. By contradiction I have proven that $(\mathbb{N},T)$ is not compact.

Is this proof correct? I was doubting if I could take $\mathbb{N}$ as a $U_i$

EDIT

Second try:

Take the open cover $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} U_{i}=\mathbb{N}$ where $U_i=\{1,2,...,i\}$ then by any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the open subcover $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}$ does not contain $\mathbb{N}$ and therefore $(\mathbb{N},T)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Asserting that $\mathbb N$ is compact means that for *every* family $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of open subsets of $\mathbb N$ whose union contains $\mathbb N$, there is a finite subset $F$ of $\Lambda$ such that $\mathbb{N}\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in F}U_\lambda$. So, assertint that $\mathbb N$ is *not* compact means that there is a family $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of open subsets of $\mathbb N$ whose union contains $\mathbb N$ for which there is no finite subset $F$ of $\Lambda$ such that $\mathbb{N}\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in F}U_\lambda$. This is indeed true. Take $\Lambda=\mathbb N$ and, for each $n\in\Lambda$, $U_n=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: I have added a much shorter proof, is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, that proof is correct.

Comment: I have to disagree that the 2nd proof is correct. It has the right idea, but falls short of actually proving in two details: Why does $\bigcup_{i=0}^n U_i$ not contain $\Bbb N$? And you have only argued that certain finite subsets of $\{U_i\}$ (those with every $U_i$ for $i \le n$) are not covers. But you need to show it for *all* finite subsets of $\{U_i\}$. Both of these are easy to answer, and maybe you (John Keeper) were just abbreviating. But you will want to fill in the missing details before the proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof isn't quite correct.  If you assume that $\mathbb N$ is compact in this topology, you have to start by assuming that any open cover has a finite subcover.  Since not every set in the topology is of the form $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$, you can't assume every set in the cover is of this form, hence your second sentence is invalid.